# Snap application no sound nor listed in ALSA sound interface

Tags: sound, alsa

I have this 'Rambox' snap app, that is basically a wrapper for multiple chat/social media clients. It gives no sound, not only notifications or so, but also for reproducing whatsapp audios. No sound at all. And isn't it listed as a 'sound capable' app in the [Sound Control Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCEpl.png). (neither while idle nor when reproducing something)